# Angular - How to navigate to a form control within reactive forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a parent component which is a table of user data. I created a child component for each row in that table. The table looks like the following:

**Parent Component HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-condensed smallText" *ngIf="intakeForm.controls['tasks'].length" [formGroup]="intakeForm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selectedAll" (change)="selectAll();" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" />
            </th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Tool</th>
            <th>Role(s)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let t of intakeForm.get('tasks').controls let i = index; trackBy:trackByIndex" [taskTR]="t" [ui]="uiOptions"
            [intakeForm]="intakeForm"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Within my child component (TR), I have ab input that I am trying to name with `formControlName="Role"`.

**Child Component HTML:**

```
<td class="col-md-9" [formGroup]="intakeForm">
    <ng-select [items]="ui.adminRoles.options" 
               placeholder="Select one or more roles"
               formControlName="Role">
    </ng-select>
</td>
```

Here is an image of the current form structure:

1. This is the full form that surrounds the child component and is also passed into the child component.
2. This is what I am iterating over in the parent component. Each TR is a "task".
3. This is what I am trying to define in my child component. I want to name my input "Role" via `formControlName`.

[image]

The issue I am running into here is that when I add the `formControlName` on this current structure, I am getting the error `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'Role'`.

How can I properly nest this input in my child component so that it is within the correct location, allowing me to name it? I believe how it is currently set up, it thinks that `formControlName="Role"` is on the parent level on the which is why it can't find it.

**Update 1:**

Here is how the form is built:

Parent Component:

```
this.intakeForm = this.fb.group({
   requestor: ['', Validators.required],
   requestJustification: ['', Validators.required]
});

// Push a new form group to our tasks array
generateTask(user, tool) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.intakeForm.controls['tasks'];
    control.push(this.newTaskControl(user, tool))
}

// Return a form group
newTaskControl(user, tool) {
    return this.fb.group({
      User: user,
      Tool: tool,
      Roles: this.fb.array([])
    })    
}
```

TR Component:

```
@Input('taskTR') row;
@Input('ui') ui;
@Input('intakeForm') intakeForm: FormGroup;

// Add a new role
addRole($event, task) {
   let t = task.get('Roles').controls as FormArray;
   t.push(this.newRoleControl($event))
}

// Return a form group
newRoleControl(role) {
   return this.fb.group({
     Role: [role, Validators.required],
     Action: [null, Validators.required]
   })
 }
```

Update 2 @Chau Tran -

```
<td class="col-md-9" [formGroup]="intakeForm" *ngIf="intakeForm">
    <span formArrayName="tasks">
        <span formArrayName="Roles">
            <ng-select  
                    [items]="ui.adminRoles.options" 
                    bindLabel="RoleName" 
                    bindValue="RoleID"
                    placeholder="Select one or more roles" 
                    formControlName="Role"
                    [multiple]="true"
                    [clearable]="false" 
                    (add)="addRole($event, row)" 
                    (remove)="removeRole($event, row)">
            </ng-select>
        </span>
    </span>
</td>
```

I tried nesting it like this with just `tasks` and just `roles` and then both. For the example `TaskRowComponent.html:8 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'tasks -> Roles'`, `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'tasks -> Roles -> Role'`

Update 3 @ Chau Tran -

```
<td class="col-md-9" [formGroup]="intakeForm" *ngIf="intakeForm">
    <span formArrayName="tasks">
        <span [formGroupName]="taskIndex"> <!-- Comes from ngFor in parent -->
            <span formArrayName="Roles">
                <span [formGroupName]="0"> <!-- Only one Roles group per task -->
                    <ng-select  
                            [items]="ui.adminRoles.options" 
                            bindLabel="RoleName" 
                            bindValue="RoleID"
                            placeholder="Select one or more roles" 
                            formControlName="Role"
                            [multiple]="true"
                            [clearable]="false" 
                            (add)="addRole($event, row)" 
                            (remove)="removeRole($event, row)">
                    </ng-select>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</td>
```

I set up my HTML like so. This produces the following errors:

`ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'tasks -> 0 -> Roles -> 0'` and `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'tasks -> 0 -> Roles -> 0 -> Role'`.

I think this is closer but I am unsure why its not working. Appears to be the correct path.

Comment: Have a look on this article https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html
You should post how you built your `intakeForm` on the component.ts

Comment: @n4nd0_o - Thanks, updated post with the form structure.

Comment: You still need to reference formArrayName=Roles

Comment: or formArrayName=tasks.

Comment: @ChauTran - Updated my post with your suggestion.

Comment: Your form has this: intakeForm -> formArray tasks -> each element of formArray tasks -> formArrayRoles -> each element of formArray Roles -> formControl Role. The error suggested that there is no direct path from tasks -> roles because there’s no such thing. However tasks[0] -> Roles is valid

Comment: @ChauTran - Updated the OP with the new structure, I feel this is close but still missing something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162529/discussion-between-chau-tran-and-sbb).